# Microsoft Graph API - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API to update another user in Active Directory.

I have the following permissions set for both user and application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

I've requested the following scopes:

- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- User.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All

I am able to get a listing of all users in the directory, but when trying to update (in this case, the `city`) it fails:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient ();
var usersResponse = graphClient.Users.Request ().GetAsync ();
var users = usersResponse.Result;

// hard coding user id for now
var userId = "9a5b83cd-85ff-4ad1-ab2f-b443941a518e";

var user = users.FirstOrDefault (m => m.Id == userId);
if (user != null) {
    user.City = "New York";
    await graphClient.Me.Request ().UpdateAsync (user);
}
```

I get:

```cs
{
    Code : Authorization_RequestDenied
    Message : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
    Inner error
}
```

The user I am logged in as is a Global Administrator of the directory.

I took the JWT token, headed over to https://jwt.io and these are the roles I am seeing:

- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Files.ReadWrite
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Mail.Send
- User.Read
- User.Read.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

Do I need other permissions to make this happen?

At the end of the day, I'd like to create a console app (not web app) that I can update other user information in the directory. But I figured using this sample app provided by Microsoft is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because you're passing the complete `user` object rather than only the `city` property. In other words, you're attempting to update *every property* in that `user` record, including several that are read-only.

This is one of those cases where having an SDK that wraps a REST API can be result in some confusing errors. As REST API, it is stateless so passing in the entire `user` property set is telling the API you want to `PATCH` all of those values.

You're also passing in a different `user` object into the `me` object (i.e. you're replacing all of your property values with this other user's property values):

`await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(user);`

Instead, try this:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient ();

// hard coding user id for now
var userId = "9a5b83cd-85ff-4ad1-ab2f-b443941a518e";

await graphClient.Users[userId].Request ().UpdateAsync(new User
{
    City = "New York"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link worked for me:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-reset-or-update-user-passwords-with-microsoft-graph-api-in-azure-ad-c6733c3b0ac3

Basically, adding a suitable role to the apps servicePrincipal seemed to kick it into working.

I'll be honest, still a little bit vague on what servicePrincipal is, and still no idea why my app stopped working in the production tenant while still working in the test with AFAICT identical settings.

Instructions will probably need adjusting for your environment: for example, it suggests using role “Helpdesk Administrator” which did not exist in my environment.

Hint: If using AzureAD powershell module, make sure you connected to the correct TenantId if you have multiple tenants.